# C Container Libraries

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone have a good recommendation for a C container library that would provide the same functionality as a C++ standard library?  I know I could simply just use C++, however trying to stay with pure C.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) and [libavl](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/avl).

Comment: If you don't mind a huge library, take a look at [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.62/glib-data-types.html).  This does way more than just containers.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the suggestions @HenriMenke